# playing audio in chrome extension results DOMException

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to play audio in my chrome extension but I keep getting this error:

> DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

I'm really not sure how to solve this issue

```
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = "/Users/jadslim/Desktop/youtube\ video\ like/bundle/sound/Pop.wav";
myAudio.play().catch(function(error) {
console.log(error)
});;
```

Comment: To make it a valid URL you need a scheme: `file:///Users/.....` And of course `[x] Allow access to file URLs` on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: If the audio file is in the extension package itself then you need to prepare chrome:// url else a file:// url would work or even we can use http url

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].